# c++ nlohmann json saving 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays, json, mapping, 2d

```
struct MyStruct {
    Items item[100][60];
    string Something;
    int X;
    int Y;
};
```

I have this struct "MyStruct" with a 2D Array of 100 * 60.
If I want to save the struct in Json Array for the item[100][60]
how I can do it using nlohmann json?
could anyone help me please?
Or if there is a way to save as binary file without using boost, I'll take that too.

```
void Save(std::string name, MyStruct test) {
    std::string filename = name + ".dat";
    std::ofstream out(filename);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive binary_output_archive(out);
    binary_output_archive& test;
    out.close();
}

void Read(std::string filename) {
    std::ifstream in(filename + ".dat");
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive binary_input_archive(in);
    MyStruct test;
    binary_input_archive& test;
    in.close();
}
```

I tried this but it also crash sometimes so I want a better way

Comment: You're asking two different questions, either you want a JSON object or you want to serialise `MyStruct` - which is it?

Comment: save the MyStruct x , y , items[100][60]  values in json file

Answer (score 0):

```
void Save(const std::string& name, const MyStruct& test) {
    auto result = nlohmann::json{
        {"item", json::array()},
        {"Something", test.Something}
        {"X", test.X},
        {"Y", test.Y},
    };

    for (auto i = 0u; i < 100u; ++i) {
        auto& outer = result["item"];
        for (auto j = 0u; j < 60u; ++j) {
            // You'll need to convert whatever Items is into a JSON type first
            outer[i].push_back(test[i][j]);
        }
    }

    auto out = std::ofstream out(name + ".dat");
    out << result;
}
```

Something like this will suffice for saving, you can work out the deserialisation from this and [the docs](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#serialization--deserialization).

I **strongly** advise that you do not use `Items item[100][60]`, the stack is not for items that large.  Use a vector of `std::array`s to use the heap but retain the same memory layout.

Comment: what should i use tho? im adding pathfinding to my game